# How to use different variables at specific times in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I have some PHP code..

```
<?php
  $artist = $_GET['artist'];
  $title = $_GET['title'];

  $r = fopen("temp_title.txt", "w");
  fwrite($r, $artist." <b>|</b> ".$title);
  fclose($r);
?>
```

and I would like to add another `fwrite` with a different variable, but it will be displayed for a certain period of time, from 11pm to 7am. Like this:

```
<?php
  $artist = $_GET['artist'];
  $title = $_GET['title'];
  $info = "Night Mode";

  $r = fopen("temp_title.txt", "w");
  fwrite($r, $artist." <b>|</b> ".$title);
  fwrite($r, $info); //This will be shown only in time of 11pm - 7pm
  fclose($r);
?>
```

and after that time, the previous `fwrite` should be displayed again..

Comment: You are just writing text to a text file. What do you mean by display or show? You can put an IF statement around second fwrite but this will only decide if $info is 'written' between 11pm and 7pm or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the current hour of the day and use that to control the data that is written to the file:

```
$artist = $_GET['artist'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
$r = fopen("temp_title.txt", "w");
$hour = date('G');
if ($hour < 7 || $hour >= 23) {
    fwrite($r, "Night Mode"); //This will be shown only in time of 11pm - 7pm
}
else {
     fwrite($r, $artist." <b>|</b> ".$title);
}
fclose($r);
```

Comment: Yes, but during this time, the first fwrite should be deactivated

Comment: @Mark in your question you do the first write regardless of whether it is night or not.

Comment: The text that was written by the first fwrite should be deleted and that at 11pm the second text should be printed and then at 7am to erase the text of the second fwrite and re-print the text of the first fwrite, if you understand me xd

Comment: @Mark no problem - that's what SO is for.